# How to only disable to scroll when the space bar is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see every answer being e.preventDefualt but that doesn't help my case. My scenario is that i want to prevent only the scrolling part of the space bar. When I use e.preventDefault it stops the scroll but it also makes it so when in a text box I can not type a space in it. So i was wondering if there is a way to prevent the scroll but allow actually typing the space.

```
onWindowKeyDown = function(e){
  switch(e.which){
    case 9:
      e.preventDefault();
    break;
    case 32:
      console.log(e);
      e.preventDefault();
    break;
  }
};
```

ok so i have tried this and I have tried stopPropagation and the immediate version as well. Only preventDefualt actually stops the scrolling but when i go to type in the text box it does not allow me to type actual spaces.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: I spent most of the day looking for an answer actually and the difficulties that prevented me from solving it myself like i said is that, everyone says to use e.preventDefualt but that doesn't solve my problem and i haven't seen anyone else have my problem either.

Comment: Please just show some code with what you've tried and what your research showed. Like it says in the article I linked to: *Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [mcve].*

Answer (score 0):

I don't have code to reference to verify this, but off the top of my head, I believe you could check the target of e to see if it's an input element.  If e.target is not an input or texarea, then preventdefault?

Comment: Well its not that i need to have it prevented sometimes vs others. Its that i need it to have only the scrolling part prevented.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you could check the target of the event to check if the element which has been the target of the keypress was the input element or not. If the target was the body of the html, you could prevent the scrolling. here is a working link : https://jsfiddle.net/Lgyrn5bd/

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 32 && e.target == document.body) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
};
```

When you check the target of the event (e.target) the target would be input/textarea if you were typing in an element else it would be the body. So you can keep the space bar operational when you're actually typing in input elements

Comment: That fixed it, thanks so much i would upvote your answer as well but i just started on stack overflow.

Comment: i'm glad i could help :)